# external css file loading but not being applied

Tags: css

***Wetware Error***

It was a typo - there were 2 different css files with similar names and I was linking to one on one site and another on the other

Apologies from a muppet :(

***Closed***

I have the following line in an html head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://files.hypernumbers.com/redesign/frontpage.css">
```

When I view this page from the domain `hypernumbers.com` it loads fine and then is applied.

But when I view the same page from the domain `hypernumbers.dev` it loads (Firebug and Chrome tools show me that the CSS file is there) but it isn't applied to the page

Is there some sort of domain precedence/sub-domain thing going no that I don't know about?

**Update**

Tried it in Opera where it doesn't load in either `hypernumbers.com` or `hypernumbers.dev`...

Comment: Is the behavior consistent across all major browsers?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox (my dev box is on Linux so that's your lot)

Comment: well, that's not entirely true, there's Opera too.

Comment: I had the same problem but instead of linking like this
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://files.hypernumbers.com/redesign/frontpage.css">
I tried this way
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//files.hypernumbers.com/redesign/frontpage.css">
This works fine for me and solved my problem

Answer (score 36):

This is a pretty old question, but since it's the top result in Google I'll put my solution here.

I was having the same issue, my CSS files were accessible and were being downloaded by the browser, but they weren't actually being applied.  I could browse to the CSS manually just fine, but both Firefox and Chrome weren't applying them.

This was my link tag:

```
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Looks fine, that's the correct path... I even remembered to set the type, but no dice.

As is turns out, my web server was forcing the content-type on CSS files to `application/octet-stream`.  So even though I specified `type` in the link tag, both Firefox and Chrome were seeing the wrong content-type from the server and refusing to apply the stylesheets.

If you're using Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) installed you can see the content-type your server is sending on the "Net" tab.

In my case, using Lighttpd, the fix was to add `".css" => "text/css"` to `mimetypes.assign` like so:

```
mimetype.assign     = ( ".html" => "text/html",
                        ".txt" => "text/plain",
                        ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
                        ".png" => "image/png",
                        ".css" => "text/css",
                        "" => "application/octet-stream" )
```

Hope this saves someone from a couple hours of Googling and head scratching.

Comment: And if you're using nginx, make sure to [add `include mime.types;` in the `http{}` section of your config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55535670)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit of a crazy guess, but if you add in the attribute `type="text/css"` does that make any difference? Also, what's the encoding on the CSS file and the html document?

As a last check, have you considered downloading the file and making a local copy? Just to ensure that there's nothing between your network and [Hypernumbers](httP://hypernumbers.com) causing issues?

Comment: Good suggestion, I tried that and it doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: well I did discover that Opera will give you lovely error messages for all your CSS typos so I did manage to fix up half a dozen little niggly things that *might have become bugs* which is schweet :)