# CSS didn't work after migration of django website into another instance

Tags: css, django, migration

I used amazon ec2 to host my website. I wanted to switch from redhat to amazon linux because the latter is cheaper. After I configured apache server and the django settings for my website, everything worked fine but the layout of html. The css didn't work at all. However, if I compare the source file of the html with that of in my own laptop, they look the same.

From the html source file, the link of the css file is correct, i.e, if you click the link, you can see the css file. But I don't know why the background picture didn't show up, and the sidebar is below the content. Everything is as if there is no css.

Have anybody encountered this weird situation before?

Comment: Then the url to the background picture must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: @AbhiP The url is correct, I can access the picture if I type its address in browser. But not just the picture went wrong, the layout of css didn't work at all

Comment: Can you share the URL of your website?

Comment: Sure. The login page is the easiest to see the problem: http://threelifestone.com/blog/login_page/

Comment: Try changing the `type` attribute your `<link>`s to `text/css`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [external css file loading but not being applied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850373/external-css-file-loading-but-not-being-applied)

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome DevTools reports:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain.`

Response Headers for your css file:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1892
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 05 Jun 2015 06:39:54 GMT
ETag: "40945-764-517bea2cb7b4f"
Last-Modified: Fri, 05 Jun 2015 05:33:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon)
```

You need to configure Amazon web server and set correct content type for styles.

Next link can help you https://serverfault.com/questions/405229/apache-delivering-css-and-js-files-but-browsers-dont-render-them

Comment: Thanks for respond! I added the type="text/css" in the <link>, I also configured the httpd.conf with AddType as you suggested. Now chrome devtool shows the type of css is stylesheet. But still, css didn't work

Comment: Now, it works! I guess it might took some time for refresh... Thanks a lot!